# Condition for Homography in Computer Vision

Tags: geometry

Question: What condition should exist between two set of points so there will be a homography.
I was asked that question during the interview and I did not fully understand it.

I would appreciate if you can give me all relevant information about conditions for homography, or the essence of relation between two set of points.
Or there might be another formulation: What transformation should be for set of points, in order that there will be a homography between the original set and transformed set.

Thanks in advance,
Dany